# If I use Facebook for authentication, is regular HTTP fine?

Tags: facebook, http, authentication, ssl, https

Can the Stack Overflow community sanity-check this for me?

I am working on a project that involves two components: an iOS app and a mobile website. It's for a product that will interact pretty heavily with Facebook. The website is hosted on Heroku.

From iOS land, my intention is to use the Facebook iOS SDK for authentication and then hit the web API with the user's access token at https://[myappname].herokuapp.com. Since Heroku offers piggyback SSL when using the herokuapp.com domain, and the user won't be seeing this URL anyway, I figure that's fine. And this way the request is encrypted, so the access token should be safe.

From the mobile website, users will log in using Facebook, at which point my understanding is that the access token will be in their cookies, which my server can then access without having to exchange it back and forth with each request. By this reasoning it seems to me I can just stick with regular unencrypted http:// URLs for the website (and therefore use my custom domain name without having to pay a monthly fee for Heroku's SSL Endpoint add-on).

Does this all make sense? I will be the first to admit my understanding of a lot of this stuff is in serious need of an upgrade. But for now I'm just looking for someone who can tell me, "No, you're totally overlooking/misunderstanding XYZ" or "Yeah, this is how it's generally done."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook advises that you should not take a dependency on their cookie format.  They have stated that the cookies are "an implementation detail" that they may tweak at any time with no notice given.  You should not directly access the token or other user info directly from the cookie.  I personally have had some bad experiences trying to get user information directly from the cookies, mostly due to timing -- they were not always there or updated when I expected them to be.

Client-side, you should either get the access token from the Javascript SDK via FB.getLoginStatus or other method that returns the access token, and then post it up to your server.  This should really be done using ssl otherwise you are susceptible to network packet sniffing where a black hat could grab the token and be able to use all of the privileges the user granted your app.

There is also a server-side option as well which hits at ssl endpoint on Facebook's servers to return an access token.

References:

"Cookies are an implementation detail":  https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/624/
Authentication docs:  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Interesting. I'm actually using the Koala gem to parse the cookie. So I guess really the author of Koala is going against Facebook's advice on that one?

Comment: Yes.  Many Facebook SDKs take direct dependencies on the cookies, and it is only in the last 6 - 8 months that Facebook started directly discouraging this approach.  I use the C# SDK for Facebook, which at one point in its history did this as well before migrating to more of a reference implementation using Facebook's OAuth endpoints.

Answer (score 1):

Website login via Facebook works totally fine via HTTP.

Comment: FTP login using clear text passwords on the wire also works totally fine.  Until someone sniffs your packet and steals your password.  Then it works totally fine for them too!

Comment: This is a different matter, though. Users don’t login “on” your website, they login with Facebook – well, OAuth for short.

Comment: granted, but the question is about how to get a user's accesstoken from the client to the server and whether there are any security concerns with doing so over unencrypted http.